# Delphi - TInterfaceList descendant to support more types - Abstract Error

Tags: delphi, list, interface, abstract

I have a class TRow = class(TInterfaceList) where the items I want to add are descendants from IField (TFieldType1 and TFieldType2)
I have a method where I want to iterate through the items and call an IField method on them:

```
(Item[i] as IField).IFieldMethod
```

And I am getting Abstract Error?
What am I doing wrong? Am I wrong in my OOP understanding or Delphi?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a class implementing `IField.IFieldMethod` using a `abstract virtual` method, and you ignored a `Constructing instance of <TType> containing abstract method <MethodName>`.

Here's a short console demo of code that exhibits your error. The fact that you're calling `IFieldMethod` using `(Item[i] as IField).IFieldMethod` doesn't provide any new information, it only hides the cause of the problem. Store the `IField` type interface reference to a local variable and you've got my code:

```
program Project23;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

type IDummyIntf = interface
  procedure DoStuff;
end;

type TDummyImp = class(TInterfacedObject, IDummyIntf)
  procedure DoStuff;virtual;abstract; // TDummyImp implements IDummyIntf.DoStuff using a VIRTUAL ABSTRACT method.
end;

var X: IDummyIntf;
begin
  X := TDummyImp.Create; // <-- Warning at this line, Constructing instance of TDummyImp containing abstract method TDummyImp.DoStuff 
  X.DoStuff; // This raises EAbstractError because TDummyImp doesn't actually implement DoStuff
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: I mis-read the question and then my internet connection died before I could delete my stupid answer. Now that it's back I note that you have given a correct answer. +1

Comment: True. I have a TField implementing an IField and TFieldType1 and TFieldType2 implementing TField where IFieldMethod is virtual; abstract; in TField. I FORGOT to override; the method in the TFieldType1 and FieldType2.
So this is my error. I am writing this explanation so someone browsing for a similar error could understand.
Thank you.

Comment: **Beware**: If you instantiate the classes indirectly, through a metaclass, then the compiler does *not* issue the warning about abstract methods (because it can't detect the problem anymore).